# ubuntu 14.04 only boots in recovery mode

Tags: boot, nvidia, graphics, xorg, amd-processor

I have the same problem in my Ubuntu desktop, then

- if I change the X.Org X server-Nouveau driver for the NVIDIA one, the display crashes next reboot (even in recovery mode) so only reinstall option remains.
- the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file doesn't exist
- the display settings only show 1024x768 and 800x600 resolutions

description: CPU
product: AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 955 Processor
vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
physical id: 3
bus info: cpu@0
version: AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 955 Processor
serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
slot: CPU 1
size: 3200MHz
capacity: 3200MHz
width: 64 bits
clock: 200MHz

So, please, these are my questions:

- Can somebody advice me how can I have a stable ubuntu OS?
- Some suggestion about configure or add a file concerning to graphics?

Thanks,
Gbrunati

Comment: Try running (if you can) `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg` and `sudo dpkg --configure xserver-xorg`.

Comment: thanks Zacharee,   gbrunati@conse:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
dpkg-query: package 'xserver-xorg' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: xserver-xorg is not installed
gbrunati@conse:~$ sudo dpkg --configure xserver-xorg
dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg (--configure):
 no package named `xserver-xorg' is installed, cannot configure
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xserver-xorg

Comment: Oh sorry. It seems like Nvidia replaces the X server with its own thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could try upgrading to the latest:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa -y 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

If this doesn't work can you send us the results of `lspci -v | grep VGA` so we know what card you have.

Also what version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: This repository holds new dangers for inexperienced users.

Comment: These are my specs:
ubuntu 14.04 LTS
gbrunati@conse:~$ lspci -v | grep VGA
00:0d.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

Comment: If I try to install NVIDIA, then it will froze when I open and try to use Chrome